# Keycloak force refresh token

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak with an AngularJs client and a REST java backend (using Play Framework 2.6).

I'm using `openid-connect`. The client is configured with *Access Type* `public` while the REST server is configured as `bearer-only`.
I'm using the `Keycloak JS adapter` with the client and the `Keycloak Java adapter` with the REST server.

Authentication works fine.
Using the `java admin-cli` from the REST server I'm adding an `attribute` to the user and using a custom `mapper` this `attribute` is added directly in the `Access token`.

The problem is that when I add or update this attribute I can't see the updated value in the `Access token`.
I can only see it after a *logout - login* or a *reload* of the client.

How can I force the refresh of the access token from the REST server?
There are other strategies to see the updated attribute in the Access Token?

Comment: To force refresh the token use `keycloak.updateToken(-1)` where `-1` means **force** update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `bearer-only` it won't be possible to refresh the token. Are you using `keycloak.updateToken()` on the client side ? 
Other option is to call the `user-info` endpoint from your REST server but not sure it interest you since it won't be in the token.

Comment: I found a solution updating the token using `keycloak.updateToken()` on the client.